# SSRS: How to use OR to combine to AND expressions

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to write an expression that will do the following:
If this field equals this text AND the day difference between the created and the arrival date is less than 90 days, then make it red, otherwise white
OR
If this field equals this text and the day difference between the created and the arrival date is less than 60 days, then make it red, otherwise white

Here is the expression I have so far.

```
 =iif((Fields!Type.Value="Discovery Email Sent") 
  and (datediff("d",Fields!CreatedDate.Value,Fields!ArrivalDate.Value)<90),"red","white")
 or (iif((Fields!Type.Value="Menu Proposal Sent") and
 (datediff("d",Fields!CreatedBy.Value,Fields!ArrivalDate.Value)<60),"red","white"))
```

They both work by themselves, but when I put them together with "OR" nothing turns red even though the conditions are being met.

Any thoughts?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=iif
(((Fields!Type.Value="Discovery Email Sent") and (datediff("d",Fields!CreatedDate.Value,Fields!ArrivalDate.Value)<90)) 
or 
((Fields!Type.Value="Menu Proposal Sent") and (datediff("d",Fields!CreatedBy.Value,Fields!ArrivalDate.Value)<60)),
"red","white")
```

The spacing is just for clarification. I've combined these conditions into one statement that executes if either of these two conditions (which are themselves composed of two conditions) you specified are met.

Answer (score 0):

Make those two blocks separate.
Instead of:

```
if((Fields!Type.Value="Discovery Email Sent") and (datediff("d",Fields!CreatedDate.Value,Fields!ArrivalDate.Value)<90),"red","white") or (iif((Fields!Type.Value="Menu Proposal Sent") and (datediff("d",Fields!CreatedBy.Value,Fields!ArrivalDate.Value)<60),"red","white"))
```

Use:

```
if(((Fields!Type.Value="Discovery Email Sent") and (datediff("d",Fields!CreatedDate.Value,Fields!ArrivalDate.Value)<90),"red","white")) or (((Fields!Type.Value="Menu Proposal Sent") and (datediff("d",Fields!CreatedBy.Value,Fields!ArrivalDate.Value)<60)),"red","white")
```